# Kinect SDK 1.5 - Face Tracking : WPF color-depth only tracker

Tags: wpf, kinect

I'm working on the new kinect SDK for face tracking and I noticed some differences between managed and unmanaged code provided with the examples ([Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719410/kinect-sdk-1-5-face-tracking-wpf-tracking-problems)). I can't reproduce the fast c++ example using c# and WPF: starting with the same setting with kinect for windows, here's the two sets of code:

c++:

```
if (m_KinectSensorPresent && m_KinectSensor.GetVideoBuffer())
{
    HRESULT hrCopy = m_KinectSensor.GetVideoBuffer()->CopyTo(m_colorImage, NULL, 0, 0);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hrCopy) && m_KinectSensor.GetDepthBuffer())
    {
        hrCopy = m_KinectSensor.GetDepthBuffer()->CopyTo(m_depthImage, NULL, 0, 0);
    }
    // Do face tracking
    if (SUCCEEDED(hrCopy))
    {
        FT_SENSOR_DATA sensorData(m_colorImage, m_depthImage, m_KinectSensor.GetZoomFactor(), m_KinectSensor.GetViewOffSet());

        FT_VECTOR3D* hint = NULL;
        if (SUCCEEDED(m_KinectSensor.GetClosestHint(m_hint3D)))
        {
            hint = m_hint3D;
        }
        if (m_LastTrackSucceeded)
        {
            hrFT = m_pFaceTracker->ContinueTracking(&sensorData, hint, m_pFTResult);
        }
        else
        {
            hrFT = m_pFaceTracker->StartTracking(&sensorData, NULL, hint, m_pFTResult);
        }
    }
}
```

c#:

```
int hr;
            HeadPoints headPointsObj = null;
            Vector3DF[] headPoints = GetHeadPointsFromSkeleton(skeletonOfInterest);

        if (headPoints != null && headPoints.Length == 2)
        {
            headPointsObj = new HeadPoints { Points = headPoints };
        }

        this.copyStopwatch.Start();
        this.colorFaceTrackingImage.CopyFrom(colorImage);
        this.depthFaceTrackingImage.CopyFrom(depthImage);
        this.copyStopwatch.Stop();

        var sensorData = new SensorData(this.colorFaceTrackingImage, this.depthFaceTrackingImage, DefaultZoomFactor, Point.Empty);
        FaceTrackingSensorData faceTrackSensorData = sensorData.FaceTrackingSensorData;

        this.startOrContinueTrackingStopwatch.Start();
        if (this.trackSucceeded)
        {
            hr = this.faceTrackerInteropPtr.ContinueTracking(ref faceTrackSensorData, headPointsObj, this.frame.ResultPtr);
        }
        else
        {
            hr = this.faceTrackerInteropPtr.StartTracking(
                ref faceTrackSensorData, ref regionOfInterest, headPointsObj, this.frame.ResultPtr);
        }
```

The result of the same tracking call, providing the same data apparently, result false for c# and true for c++.

Any idea? I want my tracker to work besides the skeleton data, like the c++ example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, provided in this forum [Microsoft Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdk/thread/b221d15d-3d59-47b4-90e2-cef2606b1402?prof=required). You have to modify the tools the SDK gives to you, and it's not nice to mess with provided code, but it works, finally.